# Can I retrieve data without .bak file

Tags: sql-server, database

Due to some reason I have lost `.bak` backup file of my project from a SQL Server database.

Can I restore database of the project with `.MDF` & `.LDF` files?

Comment: If you do have the `.mdf` and `.ldf`, you can copy these to the SQL Server instance's data directory, and then to an "Attach database" in your SQL Server Mgmt Studio

Comment: it is even possible with only the `.mdf` file, see [this](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1894/attach-sql-server-database-without-log-file/)